# Why getting values of model parameters and reassigning of new values takes longer and longer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Python function that takes TensorFlow session, symbolic variables (tensors representing parameters of the model, gradients of the model parameters). I call this function in a loop and each subsequent call takes longer and longer. So, I wonder what might be the reason for that.

Here is the code of the function:

```
def minimize_step(s, params, grads, min_lr, factor, feed_dict, score):
    '''
    Inputs:
        s - TensorFlow session
        params - list of nodes representing model parameters
        grads - list of nodes representing gradients of parameters
        min_lr - startning learnig rate
        factor - growth factor for the learning rate
        feed_dict - feed dictionary used to evaluate gradients and score
            Normally it contains X and Y
        score - score that is minimized

    Result:
        One call of this function makes an update of model parameters.
    '''
    ini_vals = [s.run(param) for param in params]
    grad_vals = [s.run(grad, feed_dict = feed_dict) for grad in grads]
    lr = min_lr
    best_score = None
    while True:
        new_vals = [ini_val - lr * grad for ini_val, grad in zip(ini_vals, grad_vals)]
        for i in range(len(new_vals)):
            s.run(tf.assign(params[i], new_vals[i]))
        score_val = s.run(score, feed_dict = feed_dict)
        if best_score == None or score_val < best_score:
            best_score = score_val
            best_lr = lr
            best_params = new_vals[:]
        else:
            for i in range(len(new_vals)):
                s.run(tf.assign(params[i], best_params[i]))
            break
        lr *= factor
    return best_score, best_lr
```

Could it be that the symbolic variables, representing model parameters, somehow accumulate old old values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the point on how tensorflow 1.* is used. I'm not going into details here since you could find plenty of resources on the internet.
I think [this paper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) would be enough to understand the concept of how to use tensorflow 1.*.

In your example at every iteration you are continuously adding new nodes to the graph.

Let's say this is your execution graph

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))

res = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=res, labels=y)
loss_tensor = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ())
grads = tf.gradients(loss_tensor, tf.trainable_variables())
weight_updates = [tf.assign(w, w - lr * g) for g, w in zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables())]
```

Each time the `weight_updates` are executed the weights of the model will be updated.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # before
    print(sess.run(tf.trainable_variables()))
#     [array([[ 0.7586721 , -0.7465675 ],
#             [-0.34097505, -0.83986187]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
    # after
    evaluated = sess.run(weight_updates,
                         {x: np.random.normal(0, 1, (2, 2)),
                          y: np.random.randint(0, 2, 2),
                          lr: 0.001})
    print(evaluated)
#     [array([[-1.0437444 , -0.7132262 ],
#             [-0.8282471 , -0.01127395]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.00072743, -0.00072743], dtype=float32)]
```

In your example at each step you are adding additional execution flow to the graph instead of using existing one.

Comment: OK, I see the problem, but how to achieve what I want in a proper way? Cann't I assign values to model parameters without extending the graph?

Comment: The problem that I try to solve is that I do not want the value of learning rate to be hard coded into the computational graph. I calculate gradients and then I decide what learning rate do I want to use now.

Comment: you first create operation (`weight_updates`) that updates parameters. Each time you want to update those variables you execute this operation (`sess.run(weight_updates, ...)`). you don't need to create this operation over over again. 
For learning rate i'll update my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: @Roman See the updated answer. You define learning rate as placeholder and feed any value that you want each time you execute the weight update operation.